# When/what to cache in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Caching is something that I kind of ignored for a long time, as projects that I worked on were on local intranets with very little activity. I'm working on a much larger Rails 3 personal project now, and I'm trying to work out what and when I should cache things.

1. How do people generally determine this?
2. If I know a site is going to be relatively low-activity, should I just cache every single page?
3. If I have a page that calls several partials, is it better to do fragment caching in those partials, or page caching on those partials?

The Ruby on Rails guides did a fine job of explaining how caching in Rails 3 works, but I'm having trouble understanding the decision-making process associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever cache for the sake of it, cache because there's a need (with the exception of something like the homepage, which you know is going to be super popular.) Launch the site, and either parse your logs or use something like [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/) to see what's slow. From there, you can work out what's worth caching.

Generally though, if something takes 500ms to complete, you should cache, and if it's over 1 second, you're probably doing too much in the request, and you should farm whatever you're doing to a background process…for example, fetching a Twitter feed, or manipulating images.

**EDIT:** [See apneadiving's answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843163/when-what-to-cache-in-rails-3/7843259#7843259), he links to some great screencasts (albeit based on Rails 2, but the theory is the same.)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to think about caching several kinds of things:

- Requests that are hit a lot, and seldom change
- Requests that are "expensive" to draw, lots of database calls, etc. Also hopefully these seldom change.

The other side of caching that shouldn't go without mention, is expiration. Its also often the harder part. You have to know when a cache is no longer good, and clear it out so fresh content will be generated. Sweepers, or Observers, depending on how you implement your cache can help you with this. You could also do it just based on a time value, allow caches to have a max-age and clear them after that no matter what.

As for fragment vs full page caching, think of it in terms of how often those parts are updated. If 3 partials of a page are never updated, and one is, maybe you want to cache those 3, and allow that 1 to be fetched live for so you can have up to the second accuracy. Or if the different partials of a page should have different caching rules: maybe a "timeline" section is cached, but has a cache-age of 1 minute. While the "friends" partial is cached for 12 hours.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If the site is relatively low activity you shouldn't cache **any** page. You cache because of performance problems, and performance problems come about because you have too much data to query, too many users, or worse, both of those situations at the same time.

Before you even *think* about caching, the first thing you do is look through your application for the requests that are taking up the most time. Not the slowest requests, but the requests your application spends the most aggregate time performing. That is if you have a request A that runs 10 times at 1500ms and request B that runs 5000 times at 250ms you work on optimizing B first.

It's actually pretty easy to `grep` through your `production.log` and extract rendering times and URLs to combine them into a simple report. You can even do that in real-time if you want.

Once you've identified a problematic request, you go about picking apart what it's doing to service the request. The first thing is to look for any queries that can be combined by using eager loading or by looking ahead a bit more to anticipate what you'll need. The next thing is to ensure you're not loading data that isn't used.

So many times you'll see code to list users and it's loading 50KB per person of biographical data, their Facebook and Twitter handles, literally everything about them, and all you use is their name.

Fetch as little as you need, and fetch it in the most efficient way you can. Use `connection.select_rows` when you don't need models.

The next step is to look at what kind of queries you're running, and how they're under-performing. Ensure your indexes are all set properly and are being used. Check that you're not doing complicated `JOIN` operations that could be resolved by a bit of tactical de-normalization.

Have a look at what data you are storing in your application, and try and find things that can be removed from your production database and warehoused somewhere else. Cycle your data out regularly when it's no longer relevant, preserve it in a separate database if you need to.

Then go over and have a look at how your database server is tuned. Does it have sufficiently large buffers? Is it on hardware that could be upgraded with more memory at a nominal cost? Too many people are running a completely un-tuned database server and with a few simple settings they can get ten-fold performance increases.

If, and only if, you still have a performance problem at this point then you might want to consider caching.

You know why you don't cache first? It's because once you cache something, that cached data is immediately stale. If parts of your application use this data under the assumption it's always up to date, you will have problems. If you don't expire this cache when the data does change, you will have problems. If you cache the data and never use it again, you're just clogging up your cache and you will have problems. Basically you'll have lots of problems when you use caching, so it's often a last resort.